# Showing accumulated messages to the user

Tags: delphi, user-interface, coding-style

I want to show the user a summary of all the relevant messages that have occurred during a code execution (e.g. parsing, algorithm, conversion, validation etc).  The messages should be showed together when the process is done.

A similar incident might occur none, one or several times.  The user should be notified if the incident occurred.  There might be several types of incidents.

I'm not sure if the scenario is clear, but maybe some code will help:

**PSEUDO-CODE:**

```
begin
  //Execute computing process//
  repeat
    Set a flag if an incident occurs
    Set another flag if another incident occurs
  until done

  //Show message to user//
  if AnyFlagIsSet then
    ShowPrettyMessageToUser     
end;
```

**EXECUTABLE DELPHI CODE:**

```
program Test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, StrUtils;

var
  i: Integer;
  tmpFlags: Array[1..4] of Boolean;
  tmpMessage: String;
  tmpChar: Char;
begin
  Randomize;
  repeat
    //Initialization//
    for i := 1 to 4 do
      tmpFlags[i] := False;

    //Will insident occur?//
    for i := 0 to 5 do
    begin
      if (Random(10) = 0) then tmpFlags[1] := True;
      if (Random(10) = 0) then tmpFlags[2] := True;
      if (Random(10) = 0) then tmpFlags[3] := True;
      if (Random(10) = 0) then tmpFlags[4] := True;
    end;

    //Show message//
    tmpMessage := '';
    if tmpFlags[1] then tmpMessage := tmpMessage + IfThen(tmpMessage <> '', #13#10+#13#10) + 'Incident 1';
    if tmpFlags[2] then tmpMessage := tmpMessage + IfThen(tmpMessage <> '', #13#10+#13#10) + 'Incident 2';
    if tmpFlags[3] then tmpMessage := tmpMessage + IfThen(tmpMessage <> '', #13#10+#13#10) + 'Incident 3';
    if tmpFlags[4] then tmpMessage := tmpMessage + IfThen(tmpMessage <> '', #13#10+#13#10) + 'Incident 4';

    Writeln('----------');
    Writeln(tmpMessage);
    Writeln('----------');

    Writeln;
    Write('Again? (Y/N) ');
    Readln(tmpChar);
  until tmpChar <> 'y';
end.
```

The code in the iteration is quiet complex in real life, of course.
And the messages are also more informative, and may even be formatted and multi-lined.

**So...**

Is there a best practice or pattern that can be used for this?
Any Delphi-component that handles this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use a `TStringList` to collect all messages. You can then either display the strings in a listbox or concatenate the strings (in this case all messages should be valid sentences).

**Pseudocode:**

```
procedure DoSomething(Log : TStrings);
begin
//...
Log.Add ('Some hint.');
//...
Log.Add ('Some error happened.');
//...
end;

DoSomething (Log);
if (Log.Count > 0) then
  LogListBox.Items.AddStrings (Log);
```

For formatted or multi-lined messages you could store HTML strings in the stringlist and use a component that can display HTML formatted text to display the messages.

**Edit:** If you want no duplicate messages, just do

```
Log.Duplicates := dupIgnore;
```

Comment: @Smasher:  I like this one, and I use TStringList a lot (maybe too much).  But how can you check if an message is already logged?  'Some hint.' should only be added to the list once.  You don't want to show 'The document contains invalid character[s]' several times.

Comment: I edited the answer. You can just set `TStringList.Duplicates` to `dupIgnore`.

Comment: Of course, but `dupIgnore` requires that the list is sorted, though.  That might not always be preferable...

Comment: +1, Maybe TStringList _is_ the ultimate answer to most problems?  :-p

Comment: @Jørn: You can check if strList.IndexOf(Message) < 0 then condition to add the new messages

Comment: @Jørn E. Angeltveit: you can subclass TStringList and override the Add where you perform an `IndexOf(S) = -1` before adding the string to the list. Not very efficient, but it works. When you want it to be more efficient, enable Sorting, set dupIgnore, and add the strings with an autoinc value as an Object (`TStringList.AddObject`). When you want to present the log to your user, sort the list with your own sorting routine (`TStringList.CustomSort`) that sorts on the autoinc value.

Comment: @The_Fox he's probably got so few messages that it is actually more efficient to do a linear search than to keep the list sorted. I would opt for IndexOf in this instance.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Maybe, maybe not. Jørn should measure it. But the IndexOf(S) is the 'just works' method. The sorting is more complex. It really depends on what Jørn wants to do. Show a few messages without complex handling, choose IndexOf. Show a lot of messages in a procedure that is performance critical, choose the Sorted method.

Comment: @The_Fox I suppose it also depends on how often you try to add duplicates.

Comment: @The_Fox, @David: In my current case, it isn't a lot of different messages (5-10) nor many iterations (5-50).  Therefore the performance is not an important aspect at this moment.  The main reason for raising the question wasn't to solve my case in particular, but to discuss pros/cons with different solutions and see if anyone knew some library/component to handle this...  As I said: I feel that I'm using/abusing the TStringList in too many cases.

Comment: I wouldn't call storing text messages in it "abusing `TStringList`". That's pretty much what it was designed for.

Comment: add a timestamp to the front of the message and the list will be sorted.

Comment: @gbrandt: But then you will get duplicates: same messages with different timestamps

Answer (score 1):

I would (where the memory requirements are not a factor) create a class which uses a hashed stringlist as a catalog, where X number of "logitems" could be inserted as objects. This allows some control over how the items are grouped. By accessing the stringlist using a normal index - you get a linear timeline. But accessing the items through it's hash-keys, you get the items grouped by content. Using a hashed stringlist is much faster to work with since it employes a lookup-table.

For an overall, application-wide solution, I have used the midas library's TClientDataset which has been with Delphi for ages. Just remember to declare "midaslib" as the first unit in your project and it's linked directly into your binary (no need to ship midaslib.dll). This gives you the benefit of fields and sorting by message/error types. As long as the record count dont get above 10k it's both fast and stable to work with.